# Using fetch_assoc for getting multiple rows doesn't work for me

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried to use this code for getting multiple rows, but it returns nothing.

```
$settings_table = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `settings`");
while ($row = $settings_table->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["website_name"];
    echo $row["website_tags"];
}
```

Apatche: 2.4, PHP: 5.5, MySQL: 5.6

Comment: Look at the PDO documentation in PHP and try again.

Comment: Still doesn't work `foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM settings") as $row) {
 print $row["website_name"];
}`

Comment: It's difficult to help, since it isn't clear what object type `$db` is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested:

```
$settings = array();
foreach ($db->query("SELECT setting_value FROM settings") as $row) {
    array_push($settings, $row['setting_value']);
}
echo $settings[0]; // Returns "Cool Flowers"
```

Or get value by key:

```
$settings = array(array(), array());
foreach ($db->query("SELECT setting_key, setting_value FROM settings") as $row) {
    array_push($settings[0], $row['setting_key']);
    array_push($settings[1], $row['setting_value']);
}
function get_value($key) { global $settings;
    $key_num = array_search($key, $settings[0]);
    return $settings[1][$key_num];.
}
echo get_value("ws_tags"); // Returns "Flowers"
```

database:

```
setting_key:setting_value
ws_name:Cool Flowers
ws_tags:Flowers
```

Comment: @halfer I know. But when the answer showed up in the review queue it wasn't so refined and it wasn't *complete* at all (see the canned comment). Thus, flagging that answer had a good effect, since the author improved it.